# unable to get property of object of json

Tags: node.js, json, ajax, ejs

I have stange issue in json iteration using ejs.
when i print 
    <%=data[0].grid%>

i get following output

```
{ active_grid: false,
 thumbnail_16_9: '1556529960827.jpg',
 thumbnails_4_3: '1556529964249.jpg'
 }
```

When i do

```
<%=data[0].grid.thumbnail_16_9%>
```

i get 1556529960827.jpg

but when i do

```
<%=data[0].grid.thumbnails_4_3%>
```

It Shows nothing.It would be great if someone could help 
Thanks in advance

Comment: it's working for me. Could you give me more code sample?

Comment: @SameeraMillavithanachchi next thing is i am generating aws link for image and append this value to it to show pre-populated image in dropify plugin. Its working for thumbnail_16_9 but not for thumbnails_4_3

Comment: try `<%=data[0].grid['thumbnails_4_3']%>`

Comment: It seems that above code is correct and can you check whether the physical image is exists.